# Using babel to transform typescript ES6 in gulp

Tags: typescript, gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I wanted to use babel to transform the ES6 output from typescript and used this syntax:

```
var gulpBabel = require('gulp-babel');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
// ...
function compileTypescript(fileSpec, folder) {
    var options = {jsx: 'react', moduleResolution: 'node', target: 'ES6'}
    return gulp
        .src(fileSpec)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(ts(options))
        .pipe(gulpBabel({presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(folder));
}
```

This generates seemingly correct code, but something **bad happens with the imports**, this ts-file import:

```
 import * as express from 'express'
```

... becomes:

```
 var _express = require('express');
 var express = _interopRequireWildcard(_express);
```

... which fails when run in node.js. ("express is not a function")  When I compile to es5 directly in the typescript compiler I get this working output:

```
var express = require('express');
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Note: I want to output ES6 since some "typings" libraries, *express-handlebars* in this case, assume ES6.  I can get this to work using ES5 ts-output, but then the typings file must be manually edited to include es6-promise symbols - which will not work well in my build pipeline.  Are there any other ways to solve this issue?

Note: I use the same babel setup with my regular ES6 javascript files and that works well.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to TypeScript expecting a default export from express but there isn't one.

They [added](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#support-for-default-import-interop-with-systemjs) an `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` flag in 1.8 to address this. As per the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html):

> Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does
>   not affect code emit, just typechecking.

Try passing it as one of your options:

```
var options = {jsx: 'react', moduleResolution: 'node', target: 'ES6', allowSyntheticDefaultOptions: true}
```

Comment: Thank you, but my problem was actually runtime - the compile went on fine.  (I also got an error with the suggested argument when passing it to tsify.) However, your documentation reference led med to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the typescript compiler **changes default option for the module flag** when switching to ES6 target.  This seems be the reason.  When fixing the *module* option to 'CommonJS', the code works fine with ES6 target and Babel transformations:

```
var options = {jsx: 'react', moduleResolution: 'node', target: 'ES6', 
    module: 'CommonJS'}
    ------------------
```

Now I can use that ES6-dependent typings file for 'express-handlebars' without mangling the d.ts-file.